# WebView не открывает url с meta refresh

Tags: java, android

WebView не может выгрузить ссылку с meta refresh.
Открывает окно "Не удалось найти страницу"

```
net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITED
```

Мой webView:

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

в манифесте я использую:

```
<application>
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
</application>
```

и в самой апликухе:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в моем коде:
в активити не нужно прописывать `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
только в

```
<application>
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

И все заработает